# How to split comma and semicolon separated string into a JSON object

Tags: java, json, string

I am not able to format below string :

```
"Sony,20,30,40;LG,1,4,8"
```

In below JSON format:

```
"reported": {
    "SETS": [
      {
        "prodName": "Sony",
        "fmtd": "20",
        "lmtd": "30",
        "lm": "40"
      },
      {
        "prodName": "LG",
        "mtd": "1",
        "lmtd": "4",
        "lm": "8"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried below code but not getting proper results.

```
String stringFromProc = "SONY,20,30,40;LG,1,4,8";
String[] array1 =  stringFromProc.split("[\\;]");
JSONObject jsonSubObject = null;
JSONObject jsonFinal = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArrayRET = new JSONArray();

for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
    String []array2 = array1[i].split("[\\,]");
    for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
        System.out.println(array2[j]);
        jsonSubObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonSubObject.put("prodName", array2[0]);
        jsonSubObject.put("mtd", array2[1]);
        jsonSubObject.put("lmtd", array2[2]);
        jsonSubObject.put("lm", array2[3]);
        jsonArrayRET.add(jsonSubObject);
        jsonFinal.put("reported", jsonArrayRET);
    }
}
```

But getting this format:

```
{"SETS":[{"lm":"40","lmtd":"30","mtd":"20","prodName":"MNP"},{"lm":"40","lmtd":"30","mtd":"20","kpiName":"MNP"},{"lm":"40","lmtd":"30","mtd":"20","kpiName":"MNP"},{"lm":"40","lmtd":"30","mtd":"20","kpiName":"MNP"},]}
```

I know that I am making loop after splitting the comma separated array but not able to get the correct approach of how to split. Someone please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the internal loop

```
String stringFromProc = "SONY,20,30,40;LG,1,4,8";
String[] array1 =  stringFromProc.split(";"); // simply use ;
// array1[0] = SONY,20,30,40
// array1[1] = LG,1,4,8

JSONObject jsonSubObject = null;
JSONObject jsonFinal = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArrayRET = new JSONArray();

for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
     String []array2 = array1[i].split(","); // simply use ,
     // create jsonobjects 
     // when i=0 mean for sony and next time i = 1 mean for LG  
     jsonSubObject = new JSONObject();
     jsonSubObject.put("prodName", array2[0]);
     jsonSubObject.put("mtd", array2[1]);
     jsonSubObject.put("lmtd", array2[2]);
     jsonSubObject.put("lm", array2[3]);
     // put every object in array 
     jsonArrayRET.add(jsonSubObject);
   }
     // finally put array in reported jsonobject
     jsonFinal.put("reported", jsonArrayRET);
```

Note : `;` and `,` are not special regular expressions characters so no escaping `\\` is required and instead of long info just read about [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) `[]`

Comment: Thanks!!This removed one extra for loop as well. I tried another code as well which is also giving me the desired result but then that was making me to use 2 FOR loops.

Comment: i glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Move
`jsonFinal.put("reported", jsonArrayRET);`

outside of 2nd loop, you are overwritting **reported** object.

```
    for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
        String []array2 = array1[i].split("[\\,]");
        for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
            System.out.println(array2[j]);
            jsonSubObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonSubObject.put("prodName", array2[0]);

            jsonSubObject.put("mtd", array2[1]);
            jsonSubObject.put("lmtd", array2[2]);
            jsonSubObject.put("lm", array2[3]);
            jsonArrayRET.add(jsonSubObject);
       }
       jsonFinal.put("reported", jsonArrayRET);
   }
```